# Assigning an interface button or shortcut to sleep.sh in xmonad

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, suspend, hibernate, xmonad

I'm into xmonad for a second day. I'm doing well so far. Got it installed on Ubuntu 12.4 from [here](https://github.com/davidbrewer/xmonad-ubuntu-conf), configured keyboard layouts, tweaked xmobar configs and etc.

For screen lock I'll use `slock`, and from my research, for power management (entering sleep on a desktop) I bet the best thing is to use `/etc/acpi/sleep.sh` directly.

So my question is, how can I call sleep.sh in a more fashionable way, without entering terminal and typing `sudo /etc/acpi/sleep.sh`? Maybe a shortcut? Or an interface button?

Also, solution should take into consideration `sudo` part, it would be nice to make my computer sleep without entering password.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Although I admit that this might be not a purely xmonad question, but more related to Linux itself.

Answer (score 1):

To put the computer to sleep without a password, you can use the ["visudo"](http://www.garron.me/en/linux/visudo-command-sudoers-file-sudo-default-editor.html) program (which you need to run with root privileges), and add an entry like:

> your_username ALL = NOPASSWD: /etc/acpi/sleep.sh

where you should replace "your_username" with what you have in your system.

Then, you can bind a keyboard-shortcut in XMonad to run this command by extending the "myKeyBindings" in the config you are referring to, for example:

```
myKeyBindings =   [
    ...
    , ((0, 0x1008FF13), spawn "amixer -q set Master 10%+")
    -- SLEEP with Mod+Shift+s
    , ((myModMask .|. shiftMask, xK_s), spawn "sudo /etc/acpi/sleep.sh") ]
```

Also, don't forget to run "xmonad --recompile" to validate the config, and restart XMonad.

Comment: Let me leave here my config for suspend and hibernate.

Add following shortcuts to xmonad.hs


    myKeyBindings =
       [
         -- sleep with Mod + Shift + s
         , ((myModMask .|. shiftMask, xK_s), spawn "systemctl suspend")
         -- hibernate with Mod + Shift + h
         , ((myModMask .|. shiftMask, xK_h), spawn "sudo systemctl hibernate")
       ]

Also, you need to give permission to run hibernate command without entering password:

    sudo visudo

and add the following line:

    username ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl hibernate